# View protocol messages of pcap file in linux command line

Tags: pcap

I am trying to view diameter messages captured in pcap file using tcpdump -r .
But I am not able to see the diameter message.
Is there any other command to view the diameter messages in a pcap file in linux command line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also if there is any command to convert pcap to text file, please share.

Comment: Try [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstshark.html), the command line counterpart to the GUI wireshark.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As Steffen Ullrich says, use tshark - `tshark -r {capture file}` for one-line summaries (same as the packet list in Wireshark), or `tshark -V -r {capture file}` for detailed information (same as the packet details in Wireshark).